# understanding insertion sort in python

Tags: python, sorting, arrays, python-3.x

I came across the below code for insertion sort in python. This works as expected. However, when I am trying to trace the program and I am stuck

```
def insertionSort(array):
for step in range(1, len(array)):
    key = array[step]
    j = step - 1
    while j >= 0 and key < array[j]:
        # For descending order, change key<array[j] to key>array[j].
        array[j + 1] = array[j]
        j = j - 1
    array[j + 1] = key
data = [4, 9, 2, 1, 3]
insertionSort(data)
print('Sorted Array in Ascending Order:')
print(data)
```

Tracing for the array data in the below snippet.

```
**1st iteration of for loop**
key = array[1] = 9
j = 1 - 1 = 0
array[j] = array[0] = 4
While 0>=0 and 9 < 4: - condition not satisfied
Now, array[j+1] = key, which means array[1] = 9
```

No changes in the array

```
**2nd iteration of for loop**
key = array[2] = 2
j = 2 - 1 = 1
array[j] = array[1] = 9
while 1>=0 and 2 < 9: - condition satisfied
array[j + 1] = array[j]
array[1 + 1] = array [1]
array[2] = array [1]

This means array[2] value becomes 9 now. 

Further, j = j -1, which means j = 0 now
Now, array[j + 1] = key
which means array[0 +1] = 2, so array[1]=2.
```

So, as of now, the order of array is like this, [4,2,9,1,3]

If it proceeds like this, how does it gets sorted in the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. What i was not accounting for, is this while conditional loop

```
while j >= 0 and key < array[j]:
```

which will continue to run as long as j >= 0 and key < array[j] for the first run of for.

In nested loops, the interior loop goes through the complete iteration for all the conditions, for every condition of exterior loop. I didn't account this, and started tracing both for and while loops together every time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to use 2 differentiators in my walkthrough. The *italicized* number is the location we are currently pointing to in the for loop. The **bold** number is the number we are "following" through the while loop.

---

Start:
arr =[4, **2**, *9*, 1, 3]
As you said, we know the 2 is better than the 9, so we swapped those. Now we compare **2** to the position before it: 4

2 < 4 = true, so we swap

[**2**, 4, *9*, 1, 3]

Since **2** is in the 0th position, we stop and move to the next part of the for loop, so now we're here:

[2, 4, 9, ***1***, 3]

1 < 9

[2, 4, **1**, *9*, 3]

1 < 4

[2, **1**, 4, *9*, 3]

1 < 2

[**1**, 2, 4, *9*, 3]

**1** is in the 0th position so bump the italics over and repeat one last time (sonic speed)

[1, 2, 4, 9, ***3***]

[1, 2, 4, **3**, *9*]

[1, 2, **3**, 4, *9*]

3 !< 2

Final array:

[1, 2, 3, 4, 9]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Start: arr =[4, 2, 9, 1, 3] As you said, we know the 2 is better than the 9, so we swapped those. Now we compare 2 to the position before it: 4

2 < 4 = true, so we swap


[2, 4, 9, 1, 3]


In this, you have mentioned after 2 takes the place of 9, it's been further compared with 4 and then moved left. My question is, where is this logic in the code snippet I pasted? As my tracing stops with 2 taking the place of 9. How does it further goes and takes the place of 4?

Comment: while j >= 0 and key < array[j]:
        # For descending order, change key<array[j] to key>array[j].
        array[j + 1] = array[j]
        j = j - 1
    array[j + 1] = key ///// It's in this section. j (so 4 currently is) is 0 and key (2) < array[j]